# How do I run JavaScript code for a set of html code that repeats in a for loop created in Django?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I have this code in html that creates a block of html code for each element in my context variable.

```
{% for car, speed in carSpeeds.items %}

<div id="car1">
    <div id="carSpeedBar">
<!-- progress bar indicating car speed value goes here -->
    </div>
</div>

<p id='result'></p>

<!-- div simply holding the variables for each iteration -->
<div class="container">
    <p id='carType'>{{ car }}</p>
    <p id='carSpeed'>{{ speed }}</p>
</div>

{% endfor %}
```

GOAL:
I would like to run this JS/JQ code for each bar that gets created

```
var bar = $('#carSpeedBar');
var result = $('#carSpeed').text();
var res = document.getElementById('result');
var width = 0;

var id = setInterval(speed, 12);

    function speed(){

        if (width < result){
            width++;
                bar.style.width = width + '%';
                res.innerHTML = width + '%';
```

This is what I have so far and it works, but this only creates the bar for the first block of html code and ignores the others and I cannot figure out why. Like, it creates a bar for Mercedes and leaves all the others blanks even though their values are coming through. My guess is that it refuses to overwrite the ID's of the elements as they might be getting duplicated somehow. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how I should go about achieving this.

Thanks.

Comment: first, an id has to be unique, you should use another way to identify the blocks you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As PRMoureu already said in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57690902/how-do-i-run-javascript-code-for-a-set-of-html-code-that-repeats-in-a-for-loop-c#comment101826152_57690902): You really should get your ids right.
You can use the [forloop.counter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for) variable inside your template to get the current iteration number starting with 1. Prepend that variable to your ids like so:

```
<div id="carSpeedBar{{forloop.counter}}">
```

Second thing to do is generalize your JavaScript so it can process multiple cars.
Wrap your snippet into a function that takes a car id as a parameter and adjust your hard-coded ids to be dynamic according to this parameter

```
function animateCarSpeed(var id) {
    var bar = $('#carSpeedBar' + id);
    //...
}
```

At last you will have to call your new generalized JavaScript function. Depending on how you include your JavaScript you would call the function from within a JavaScript file, in a new `script` element inside the template loop, or at the end of the template.

Comment: I have had a look at your solution and please forgive me but I don't think I quite understand it. I have appended the forloop.counter to my ID's like you mentioned above and have edited my js file to have a function. However, my file requires multiple ID's. Which one is to be used as a parameter and how should I type it. "animateCarSpeed(?Which ID?)"

Comment: Finally got it. Thanks to your solution and many thanks to you!